# Почему не работает условие при изменении option selecta?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!
Изучаю javascript

Делаю для практики

Код - https://jsfiddle.net/9gvnebjn/13/

```js
(function($) {

  'use strict';

  function funcFormCalc() {
    var formCalc = document.getElementsByClassName('form-calc')[0],
      formCalcResult = document.getElementsByClassName('form-calc__result')[0],

      selectHowManyTrees = document.getElementById('selectHowManyTrees'),
      selectApproximateHeightTree = document.getElementById('selectApproximateHeightTree');

    var selectVariant1 = selectHowManyTrees.value === '1',
      selectVariant2 = selectHowManyTrees.value === '2';

    var select2Variant1 = selectApproximateHeightTree.value === '1',
      select2Variant2 = selectApproximateHeightTree.value === '2';

    formCalc.onchange = function() {

      if (selectVariant1 && select2Variant1) {
        formCalcResult.innerHTML = 'variant text 1';
      } else if (selectVariant2 && select2Variant1) {
        formCalcResult.innerHTML = 'variant text 2';
      } else if (selectVariant1 && select2Variant2) {
        formCalcResult.innerHTML = 'variant text 3';
      } else {
        formCalcResult.innerHTML = 'for all variants';
      }

    };
  }
  funcFormCalc();

})(window.jQuery);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  color: #2C2D2C;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, "Helvetica CY", "Nimbus Sans L", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.form-calc {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  background: #FAFAFA;
  padding: 15px 30px;
}

.form-calc__item {
  margin-bottom: 28px;
}

.form-calc__label {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  margin: 6px 0 9px;
  letter-spacing: 0.25px;
}

.form-calc__select-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-calc__select-container:before,
.form-calc__select-container:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 7px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.form-calc__select-container:before {
  top: 16.5px;
  border-width: 0 3.5px 4px 3.5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #333 transparent;
}

.form-calc__select-container:after {
  bottom: 16.5px;
  border-width: 4px 3.5px 0 3.5px;
  border-color: #333 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.form-calc__select {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, "Helvetica CY", "Nimbus Sans L", sans-serif;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  text-indent: 1px;
  text-overflow: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 43px;
  line-height: 43px;
  border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  padding: 0 7px;
  color: #2C2D2C;
}

.form-calc__select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}

.form-calc__select option {
  padding: 3px 7px;
  border: none;
}

.form-calc__result {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #3E3F3E;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.form-calc__result-subtext {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #3E3F3E;
  letter-spacing: .6px;
  line-height: 1.25;
}

.form-calc__submit {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, "Helvetica CY", "Nimbus Sans L", sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 170px;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  background: #42BF8D;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}

.form-calc__submit:hover,
.form-calc__submit:focus,
.form-calc__submit:active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #2F8B66;
}

.form-calc__submit:focus {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,600,700&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">

<form action="#" method="post" class="form-calc" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="form-calc__item">
    <label for="selectHowManyTrees" class="form-calc__label">Label 1</label>

    <div class="form-calc__select-container">
      <select name="select1" id="selectHowManyTrees" class="form-calc__select">
        <option value="1" selected>1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>        
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-calc__item">
    <label for="selectApproximateHeightTree" class="form-calc__label">Label 2</label>

    <div class="form-calc__select-container">
      <select name="select2" id="selectApproximateHeightTree" class="form-calc__select">
        <option value="1">1 story house</option>
        <option value="2">2 story house</option>       
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-calc__item">
    <div class="form-calc__result">variant text 1</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Но условие работает не корректно при изменении option selecta.
Подскажите, где допустил ошибку?

Comment: Опишите пожалуйста что конкретно не работает?

Comment: formCalc.onchange = function() не работает по всей видимости

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перенесите вычисление значений переменных во внутрь обработчика formCalc.onchange:

```
formCalc.onchange = function() {

    var selectVariant1 = selectHowManyTrees.value === '1',
    selectVariant2 = selectHowManyTrees.value === '2';

    var select2Variant1 = selectApproximateHeightTree.value === '1',
    select2Variant2 = selectApproximateHeightTree.value === '2';

    if (selectVariant1 && select2Variant1) {
        formCalcResult.innerHTML = 'variant text 1';
    } else if (selectVariant2 && select2Variant1) {
        formCalcResult.innerHTML = 'variant text 2';
    } else if (selectVariant1 && select2Variant2) {
        formCalcResult.innerHTML = 'variant text 3';
    } else {
        formCalcResult.innerHTML = 'for all variants';
    }
};
```